# Data loss when e-mailing files: is it relevant, and how to prevent it?

Tags: image-quality, client-relations, file-format, e-mail

Only recently I came across the possibility that e-mailing files may change and damage those files. Especially when mailing *.jpgs to web-based mail servers like Gmail or Outlook.com: I wouldn't be too surprised if these services re-compressed my files—possibly even stripping the colour profile in the process.

Since I do most of my file delivery by e-mail, this may be especially relevant when mailing *.jpg versions of logos and ads.

So here come my questions:

1. Is there a risk of data loss occurring when mailing image files to certain mail services? If so, how big of an impact does it have, and on what file types? And what mail services should I look out for?
2. How can I prevent such data loss? Is a *.zip protected from recompression?

Comment: dropbox, wetransfer, google drive....give links to files to send it via email...

Comment: While it is something that designers face, I feel like this is a much more technical question than we should allow. We also don't really have a technical enough user base to give this a good answer

Comment: this is a dupe im pretty sure this was asked about 6 months ago

Comment: @joojaa [this question?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/53607/8708 "What's the best method to send and receive eps files to and from clients?")

Comment: Where have you "come across this possibility"? No email service should be doing anything to your attachments (other than possibly scanning them for a virus).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the premise of the question is not supported with any references or citations.

Comment: Vectors are usually more sensitive to data loss and it's better to zip them or to use a service such as dropbox, hightail or even a FTP for this. Your JPG issue could be caused by your own email client (email software) actually, not the one on the receiving end. For example, the default Apple mail client doesn't always react in a friendly way if you drag-and-drop the image in your email and will work better for Windows users if you really "attach" the image to your email! It's actually a relevant question that many designers have issues with. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of "certain mail services" becouse there are millions. Every domain potentially has its own mail service.

But with the "big ones", there is no risk. In all the years I have being using them I have never come across a recompressed image or modified file. In my opinion it has no sense.

But it would be interesting to have a more efficient way to send your files, like a cloud based drive or a ftp one.